# How can i get the result without ("";) or string after i scan a qr code

Tags: android, firebase

[the result after i scan this is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjmGo.jpg)

```
 public void handleResult(Result rawResult) {
    JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
    JsonObject jsonObject = (JsonObject) jsonParser.parse(rawResult.getText());
    String id = databaseReference.push().getKey();
    String name = jsonObject.get("name").getAsString();
    String phone = jsonObject.get("phone").getAsString();
    String address = jsonObject.get("address").getAsString();
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");//dd/MM/yyyy
    SimpleDateFormat minute = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    String dates = date.format(calendar.getTime());
    String minutes = minute.format(calendar.getTime());
    Data data = new Data(id, name, phone, address, dates, minutes);
    view.scantext2.setText(rawResult.getText());
```

this is my code in after i scan

Comment: What's wrong with the shared code?

Answer (score 0):

Use `replace()`

```
String oldstr = "{\"name\":\"Francis Antonio\",\"phone\":\"0965312452\",\"address\":\"Mambaoln\"}";
    String newStr = oldstr.replace("\"", "");
    Log.e("WITHOUT \"" , newStr);
```